# CSS background-image : url("...") properties have also ALT?

Tags: html, css

I am inserting images in TD's in a table with

`style="background-image: url("my_url_goes_here")`

Then I apply a transparent PNG mask in that TD so that it rounds the image corners
(same colour as background corners, and it shows the middle of the picture)

I wonder if i can write the ALT of the image in the CSS part (`style = "background-image: url()`) as if I am to write the ALT to the mask image (which is what users can save if they right click on the image), Google will index transparent masks with ALT from the  image.

If it's not clear what I'm asking, I will explain further, just ask.

Also, a friend of mine told me just minutes ago over the phone that css3-round borders can be applied to all sorts of things, not just borders, but also images etc. It'd be lovely if this is the case, i'm not sure round borders will round images too, never tried it tho' (exception as usual IE, where they show square).

Thanks.

Comment: IE supports `border-radius` as well.

Comment: yes border-radius is the way to go. I wouldn't try it on `<td>`'s though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you can't add `alt` to background images
2. Yes, it's possible - http://jsfiddle.net/TyFM7/

Comment: awesome ! :) img { border-radius: 60px; } or whatever value for rounding corners to an IMG...i'm getting rid of masks and extra code! )
​

Answer (score 1):

No css does not suppport the alt tag.

As for rounding image corners with CSS that is possible.

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` attribute is meant to provide a text-equivalent in the absence of a loaded resource. It doesn't go in background images, it goes on images, areas, etc.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.8

As for rounded corners, `border-radius` works on images as well - *even in IE*. If you want to see the current best approach to providing styles for this property, check out http://css3please.com.

```
img.rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need alt tags for background images, as you wouldn't want these actually indexed.

CSS border radius can be added to most things, here is an example of an image with the border radius added:

[Example of image with 30px border radius](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMrbg/)