# Bootstrap main header with image background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple main header which contain a navbar , I want an image background to the main header.

Here is jsfidle:http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/fgkq759n/8/

Here is html:

```
   <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

here is css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marketing-main-header_banner{
    background-image: url("https://thumb.ibb.co/eodzqU/Path_47.png" alt="Path_47");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 900px;

}
```

Here is what I have :
[image]

my solution displays navbar on top and the image is below the navbar?

Here is what I want:

[image]

what am I missing in my code???

Comment: You have `alt=` in your `background-image:` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950221/css-background-image-url-properties-have-also-alt

Comment: add as solution I will accept it

Comment: You know you can save yourself an http request and make that a gradient background instead that comes close to matching that pattern.  Would you be interested in seeing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

And add the navbar-custom class to your  opening tag, like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-custom">
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: It probably got overriden, I changed my answer now

Comment: Yes is ovewritten with bg-light, removing it works  but not perfect there is margin right side

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code i hope it's will work!

```
<div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```